# Display a list with (opened and closed) folders

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm working on a script on Foobar that displays a list of playlists with some of these playlists that can be in a folder (that can be opened or closed). For example:

[image]

As you can see there may be 2 folder levels: one on the root and one inside a folder.

I have an array (`this.data`) of these playlists & folders with some parameters as follows:

- position
- name
- Playlist (yes = 1, no = 0 i.e. a folder)
- level (0 being root)
- folder (the name of the folder this object belongs to; empty for the root)
- folderStatus (1 = open, 0 = closed)

Every time I move/change/arrange anything, that array tracks the changes and eventually is saved in a text file.

I want to display the list in a panel.
So I create another array (`this.display`) to generate a list that will be displayed knowing that I'd like the positions to be incremental by level (i.e. in the above example, if I move up one position the playlist "No Art : USB" it will go above Classical).

Here is my script, using ECMAScript 5 (I didn't find this tag available).

```
        var ind = 0;
    this.display = [];
    for (i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
        if (this.data[i].lvl == '0') {  // starting point i will loop the lvl 1 or 2 below 
            this.data[i].position = ind;
            ind++;
            this.display.push(this.data[i]); // if it's lvl 0 then it has to be displayed so i'm pushing it into the display array
            if (this.data[i].pl == '0' && this.data[i].foldState == '1') { // if this is a lvl 0 folder and it's open
                for (j = 0; j < this.data.length; j++) { // loop to check if this folder has sub items or sub folders
                    if (this.data[j].fold == this.data[i].name) {
                        this.data[j].position = 1000 + (i * 100) + j;
                        this.display.push(this.data[j]);
                        if (this.data[j].pl == '0' && this.data[j].foldState == '1') { // if there is a lvl 1 sub folder and it's opened
                            for (k = 0; k < this.data.length; k++) { // same loop as above for the lvl 2 items
                                if (this.data[k].fold == this.data[j].name) {
                                    this.data[k].position = 2000 + (i * 100) + (j * 10) + k;
                                    this.display.push(this.data[k]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            if (this.data[_.findIndex(this.data, { name: this.data[i].fold })].foldState == '0') {
                this.data[i].position = 50000 + i;
            }
        }
    }
```

So my question is twofold:

- Is my approach the right one?
- If yes, my piece of code seems too complicated and doesn't even work fully as I need to work on the 2 `else` at the end (which is going to complexify further).

Edit : here is a dump of this.data (first line is the format) :

```
FORMAT : position;name;#files in PL (-1 if folder);playlist (yes = 1);lvl;folder name (if any) belonged to;folder status (1 = open)  
0;USB;2666;1;0;;  
1;All music;43170;1;0;;  
2;Downloads;100;1;0;;  
3;No Art : USB;1;1;0;;  
4;Techno;-1;0;0;;1  
5;Classical;-1;0;0;;1  
6;Genre = Classical;20771;1;0;;  
7;Funk;-1;0;0;;1  
1008;1977;1580;1;2;Years;  
1009;1983;2176;1;2;Years;  
1010;1978;1802;1;2;Years;  
1011;1982;2766;1;2;Years;  
1012;1981;2672;1;2;Years;  
1013;1979;2189;1;2;Years;  
1014;1980;2272;1;2;Years;  
1015;Techno Not Rated;1152;1;1;Techno;  
1016;Techno Rating 5;38;1;1;Techno;  
1017;Techno All;1496;1;1;Techno;  
1018;Work is missing;17329;1;1;Classical;  
1019;Classique All;20771;1;1;Classical;  
1020;Composer missing;23;1;1;Classical;  
1021;Classique Path;5003;1;1;Classical;  
1022;Funk Rating 5;1983;1;1;Funk;  
1023;Genres;-1;0;1;Funk;1  
1024;Discs;-1;0;1;Funk;1  
1025;Years;-1;0;1;Funk;1  
1026;BPM Missing;124;1;1;Funk;  
1027;Funk All;20903;1;1;Funk;  
1028;Funk Not Rated;128;1;1;Funk;  
1029;No web discog link;3749;1;1;Funk;  
1030;Discog Release ID missing;12;1;1;Funk;  
1031;Date missing;1;1;1;Funk;  
1032;Genre = Hip Hop;532;1;2;Genres;  
1033;Genre = Funk;19906;1;2;Genres;  
1034;Genre = P Funk;415;1;2;Genres;  
1035;Maxis;2068;1;2;Discs;  
1036;Albums;18829;1;2;Discs;  
1037;Disc missing;6;1;2;Discs;
```

Edit 2: Bad way to input a list, i apologize but didnt find the right way.
Edit 3 : I pasted the final code which is now working (and also to bump this topic)

Comment: What does position represent?  I thought at first it must be x, y screen position, but I’m confused since it’s only one number

Comment: it's a simple ordered position so i can move items by one (or several) positions in another function

Comment: I see.  I don't have time to respond fully now, so I'll just give you this tip: Instead of messing around with hardcoded numbers, just compare arrays, with each successive array item representing order within that level only.   See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15686314/438615) for how you might construct a comparison function, though I suspect it could be done even more succintly.

Comment: yeah i'm afraid i didnt catch the idea, i'm sorry :(

Comment: @SebastienChemouny can you provide your "data" in your post please?

Comment: just did it, i hope it's what you were looking for

Comment: Is there any reason that you can't use json format for your data?

Comment: the script is used in Foobar and has to follow the ECMA 5 standard so i guess JSON would  work. How would that improve the problematic here ?